# Anime song (I think Naruto)

Tags: bleach, theme-song

I have a song stuck in my head and I THINK it's from Naruto or Bleach but I am not sure. I am sure it's from an anime though.

http://vocaroo.com/i/s0su2gQh82mV

Any ideas?

Comment: You would be better of checking Youtube for the openings and endings. [For example](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=naruto+op)

Comment: I did but I couldnt find it

Comment: Is there any other information you recall about the music? was it during a fight or any other information it could be a sound track.

Comment: http://www.midomi.com/ Try humming it here. I tried your vocaroo, but it didn't give any results.

Comment: Yea I tried that but it can't be found there. I recall that at the part I am whistling the song it is only a voice saying something like "So re da" the first 3 notes. After the part I whistled the music kicks in which I cannot clearly remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hummed the song in Soundhound and it recognized it thanks a lot guys! It's

> Aqua Times - ALONES

It's the 6th Bleach opening theme song.

Answer (score 3):

This tune is from Bleach, Opening 6 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xHIgXwqXGk).